# Search elements of array and return element but keep original class

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an array `my_array` that is made up of multiple `MyClass` objects. I need to search this array and return an object from the array, but keep the object's class as the original `MyClass`:

```
# my_array[0] is a MyClass object
# my_array is an Array
```

`select` works perfectly, but it returns the element as an Array and not as `MyClass`. For instance:

```
my_array.select{|element| element[:value] == "good"}
```

returns an Array.

I need to pass a `MyClass` object to my view, and this is all happening in the 'MyClassController`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Enumerable#find`:

```
my_array.find {|element| element[:value] == "good"}
```

Note: `find` returns only the first element from the array according to the condition in the block.

Comment: perfect! Thank you